# Searching records from flatfile in C++

Tags: c++

I have written a snippet in C++ to search for record in a flatfile. The code does not work though. Below is the code i have written

```
case 4:
    {
    cout<<"You Entered 4 (This Parses and searches BankAccount flatfile)"<<endl;

    inputFile>>SearchParam;
    cout<<"Enter Search criteria:"<<SearchParam;

        fstream inputFile; //file stream object
        inputFile.open("BankAccount.txt", ios::in);

    struct Bank
{
string AccountName;
string AccountNumber;
string AccountBalance;
}

//Array of bank record entries
Bank Details[20];
//Do until AccountName = SearchParam (Search by AccountName)
        i = 0;
        do{
getline(BankAccount, Details[i].AccountName,' ');
getline(BankAccount, Details[i].AccountNumber,' ');
getline(BankAccount, Details[i].AccountBalance,' ');
i++;
}
while (!BankAccount.eof()&& SearchParam != AccountName)
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile.

But I think your problem is that you change `i` in between loading `AccountName` from the file and comparing it.  So the value being compared is not yet assigned correctly.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth. It gives error during compilation and i dont seem to understand where this is from.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Bank
{
    string AccountName;
    string AccountNumber;
    string AccountBalance;
}
```

needs a semicolon:

```
struct Bank
{
    string AccountName;
    string AccountNumber;
    string AccountBalance;
};
```

'while (...)' needs a semicolon:

```
while (!BankAccount.eof()&& SearchParam != AccountName);
```